# Full height div in a table

Tags: html, css

This should be simple.  I am trying to get a grey bar in a `<td>` of a table to expand to the full height of the rest of the `<tr>`.  The problem is that the rows and cells are not fixed height.

I'm a believer in table-free layouts, so no need to convert me.  I am stuck with a table in this case, so I need to work with it and treat it nicely.

Here's the HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>
            <div class="bar"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            please<br/>
            help<br/>
            me<br/>
            stack<br/>
            overflow<br/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And the CSS:

```
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.bar {
    background: #eee;
    width: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DKQVG/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working version with just CSS changes: http://jsfiddle.net/wLtCd/1/

Basically, your TD should have a height defined, so a percentage height makes sense for its child nodes.

Secondly, your div needs to have a display property of `'table'`

Full CSS:

```
td {
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100%;
}

.bar {
    background: #eee;
    width: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    display: table;
}
```

You can remove the width part from above.

Comment: the `display: table` was exactly what I was missing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the following css style:

```
html, body 
{
     height: 100%;
}
```

AND

```
    td, table 
    {
        border: 1px solid black;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: Kate: I don't think @scim wants the html/body at 100% height. The td/table css should be enough.

Comment: Very nice, thanks.  The style on html and body does not look to be necessary though. [edit: ...as @Jose just pointed out]

Comment: It wont work if the outer container doesn't have 100% height.

Comment: @scim: Kate is right. It works in Firefox and Chrome but in IE the outer container must have 100% height in order to work.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?: http://jsfiddle.net/ymu4y/2/

I added the class `bar` to the `<td>` instead of the `<div>`.

Comment: thanks! that's not quite what I need, but it does work for the simplified example I posted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can accomplish that using just CSS, but I'm not that familiar with CSS so I would just use JQuery instead, always works best for me when I have dynamic sizings.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".bar").height($(".bar").parent().height());
});
</script>
```

I tested this and it works fine, but if you're looking for a CSS only solution I don't know anymore.  Hope that helps!